# Child Of Constraint Set Inverse with Python

Tags: python, rigging, constraints

When I try to use the "set inverse" operator in python there comes an error that it missed a context called "constraint". But I did it exactly like in the Info Panel.

```
bpy.ops.constraint.childof_set_inverse(constraint="Child Of", owner='BONE')
```

The Name of the constraint is correct and the also the owner

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to specify the context and also make sure the bone is active:

```
import bpy

pbone = bpy.context.active_object.pose.bones["Bone_name"]

context_copy = bpy.context.copy()
context_copy["constraint"] = pbone.constraints["Child Of"]
bpy.context.active_object.data.bones.active = pbone.bone
bpy.ops.constraint.childof_set_inverse(context_copy, constraint="Child Of", owner='BONE')
```

If the constraint is targeting object + vertex_group instead of armature + bone, make sure the data of the object is updated before setting the inverse. This is for example needed if the target vertex group was also generated by code:

```
mesh_ob.update_tag({'DATA'})
```

If not updated entering edit-mode of the mesh or armature will reset the set-inverse.

Answer (score 2):

**Toggle a constraint property**

As mentioned in this (possible duplicate) question [Set inverse Child OF constraints via python](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/122586/set-inverse-child-of-constraints-via-python) , simply changing the `inverse_matrix` property of a constraint does nought.  However, if another property of the constraint is toggled, for example the `target` it appears to work as expected, using the new value assigned to `inverse_matrix`

Test script, tested on simple example of single bone and default cube parent. Set cmd to `'CLEAR'` for clear and `'SET'` for set.  For all child of constraints on all pose bones of the context object.  AFAICT it doesn't need context.

```
import bpy
from mathutils import Matrix

context = bpy.context

ob = context.object
constraints = [(pb, c) for pb in ob.pose.bones
        for c in pb.constraints if c.type == 'CHILD_OF']

cmd = 'CLEAR' # or 'SET'       
for pb, c in constraints:

    if cmd == 'CLEAR':
        c.inverse_matrix = Matrix.Identity(4)    

    elif cmd == 'SET': 
        if c.target:
            mw = c.target.matrix_world
            c.inverse_matrix = mw.inverted()
    # toggle a property
    target = c.target
    c.target = None
    c.target = target
    #pb.constraints.update()
```

Notes: takes into no account the `owner_space` and `target_space`, nor the `influence` value when the script is run, which changes the calculated value for set, (have a feeling influence zero is clear)... An interpolated target matrix could be found by decomposing, lerping and slerping from identity to `target.matrix_world`.

why is this so?  Constraint properties that are set by a user (esp via UI) update the data appropriately on change.

An operator for each has been  chosen to crunch the numbers , and handle the necessary updating.  Perhaps a patch to make the python attribute update on change, not sure..

Comment: I hate to revive solved questions, however I've been earching everywhere for a proper in code solution ( aka not just mimicking the user pressing UI elements ) and this has so far been the only one I could find ( sans the `c.inverse_matrix = c.target.matrix_world.inverted()` from the linked question ). However I can't seem to get it to work. There's no errors but it doesn't seem to affect anything. I tried a few update() functions but they don't seem to help. Does this code, by itself, work currently in blender ( or 2.79 )