# How do I use bpy.ops.constraint.childof_set_inverse() in blender 4.0?

Tags: python, operator, bone.constraints

I am trying to set the inverse on my child of constraints using python. However, with the correct bone active and while in pose mode, when running:

```
bpy.ops.constraint.childof_set_inverse(constraint="Child Of", owner='BONE')
```

I get this error:

```
#Could not find constraint data for Child-Of Set Inverse
```

If found this link, which is old, but which looked worth a shot:
[Child Of Constraint Set Inverse with Python](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/19602/child-of-constraint-set-inverse-with-python)

Back when this was made, the context needed to be overridden. But with blender 4.0, contexts get overridden differently: we now use bpy.context.temp_override. Which prompted me to try the following, based off of the old solution in the link:

```
import bpy

pose_bone = bpy.context.active_object.pose.bones["Bone"]

context_override = bpy.context.copy()
context_override["constraint"] = pose_bone.constraints["Child Of"]
bpy.context.active_object.data.bones.active = pose_bone.bone

with bpy.context.temp_override(**context_override):
    bpy.ops.constraint.childof_set_inverse(constraint="Child Of", owner='BONE')
```

But I get the exact same error... Am I overriding the context wrong? Is that even the issue, or is the link I shared completely obsolete? What am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can try this code here:

```
import bpy

obj = bpy.context.active_object.pose.bones["Bone.001"]

bpy.context.active_object.data.bones.active = obj.bone
    
    
with bpy.context.temp_override(active_object=obj):
    bpy.ops.constraint.childof_set_inverse(constraint="Child Of", owner='BONE')
```

Note: I used Bone.001, which has the child of constraint. So rename that to your needs.

I tried that out, and it works. If it doesn't work for you, please provide a blend file so that i can adapt my solution to your needs because i have no idea about the naming of your bones.